# Give a Search Problem in co-NP

Tags: computability, search-problem, co-np

Ex.1. Give a Search Problem whose deciding Problem is in co-NP.

Assuming 3SAT is in NP then asking wether a given Boolean formula has a Solution is a search problem in NP right?

Then would asking wether a given Boolean formula has no Solution be in co-NP?

Comment: What do you think? Use the definitions to try and prove that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically speaking, 3-SAT is an example of **NP-Complete** problem. But your problem is only considered with **NP** problems.

We have the decision problem:

> Is a SAT problem in NP?

Obviously, it is. Because you could always verify a "certificate" in time linear to your input size (values of your literals, that is a sequences of 0s and 1s).

For your question:

> Is a un-SAT problem in co-NP? (complement to SAT problem)

We could find the following definition:

> A decision problem X is a member of **co-NP** if and only if its
>   complement X is in the complexity class NP [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP).

Therefore, un-SAT is **co-NP** by definition.